# Prove that if $X$ is subgaussian, then ${\bf E}e^{tX}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}{\bf E}X^k$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

> Prove that if $X$ is subgaussian, then
>   $${\bf E}e^{tX}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}{\bf E}X^k$$

So basically I just need to push the integral through the infinite sum
$${\bf E}e^{tX}=\int_{\bf R}e^{tx}d\mu_X=\int_{\bf R}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tx)^k}{k!}d\mu_X$$
Thus I'll use the dominated convergence theorem, bounding the absolute value of the partial sums by the (hopefully) $\mu_X$-integrable function $e^{|tx|}$,
$$\Big|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(tx)^k}{k!}\Big|\leq e^{|tx|}$$
Now to show $e^{|tx|}$ is $\mu_X$-integrable, I have
$$\int_{\bf R}e^{|tx|}d\mu_X=\;\;?$$

So by the subgaussian property of $X$ I have that
$$P(|X|\geq\lambda)\leq\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}2cCxe^{-cx^2}dx=Ce^{-c\lambda^2}$$
for $c,C>0$ fixed and for any $\lambda>0$.

Hence this integrand almost functions as my **pdf** for $X$, and if it did I could use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to solve this.  However even though any upper-tailed integral of it bounds that of the actual **pdf**, I can't quite see how to use it to bound the integral of $e^{|tx|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the subgaussian property can be written as
$$P(e^{|tX|}\geq\lambda)=P(|X|\geq\frac{\log\lambda}{|t|})\leq Ce^{-c(\frac{\log\lambda}{|t|})^2}$$
Thus we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\bf R}e^{|tx|}d\mu_X={\bf E}e^{|tX|}&=\int_0^{\infty}P(e^{|tx|}\geq\lambda)d\lambda\\
&\leq C\int_0^{\infty}e^{-c(\frac{\log\lambda}{|t|})^2}d\lambda\\
&=|t|C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-cu^2+|t|u}du\\
&=|t|Ce^{\frac{-t^2}{4c}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-c(u-\frac{|t|}{2c})^2}du
\end{align}

The last integral being clearly finite by reference to the Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Until $\int_{\bf R}e^{|tx|}\rm d\mu_X$  things are fine (decomposition afterward needs symmetric measure). Now w.l.o.g. assume that $t>0$ and write:
$$
\int_{\bf R}e^{t|x|}\rm d\mu_X=\int_0^{\infty}e^{tx}\rm d\mu_X+\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-tx}\rm d\mu_X.
$$
We bound the first term and the second term is bounded similarly.
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{tx}\rm d\mu_X=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{tx}e^u\rm \;du\rm\; d\mu_X\\
=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{0}^\infty e^u\rm \;du\rm\; d\mu_X+\int_0^{\infty}e^u\int_{{u}/{t}}^{\infty}\; \rm d\mu_X \rm \;du\\
=\mu_X([0,\infty))+\int_0^{\infty}e^u
\mathbb P(X>{\frac{u}{t}})\rm \;du.
$$
Now the last integration can be bounded as:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^u
\mathbb P(X>{\frac{u}{t}})\rm du\leq \int_0^{\infty}e^uCe^{-cu^2/t^2}\rm\;du,
$$
which is bounded for $t>0$. Similarly one can show that $\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-tx}\rm d\mu_X$ is bounded and hence the total expectation is bounded.

Comment: It seems like subgaussianity condition is superfluous.

Comment: @A.S. To be honest I couldn't follow all of Arash's integral manipulations (which is why I provided my own solution once I came up with it), but I feel that subgaussianity (or at least sub-exponential tails) must be required for $\int_{\bf R}\exp(|tx|)d\mu_X$ to have any hope of existing.

Comment: @Thoth That's not true. Exponential distribution is not subgaussian and it has a well-defined mgf (though not for all $t$) and there must be plenty of distributions with mgf defined on all of R that are not subgaussian. Subgaussian tells you that cumulant generating function grows slower than some quadratic. That's a severe restriction.

Comment: @A.S. ah! well I stand corrected.

Comment: @Thoth, well, my integral manipulation is nothing but deriving directly what you have written above.

Comment: @Thoth Poisson distribution has mgf everywhere defined and is not subgaussian. This shows that normal is a bad approximation for Poisson in the tails. The expansion in the OP holds inside the interval of convergence of mgf without any restrictions on $X$.

Comment: @A.S. no restrictions on $X$ because we can always set the interval to be $[0,0]$ correct?

Comment: @Thoth Yes and no. If mgf exists for some $t\ne 0$, then the OP holds on $(-r,r)$ where $r$ is sup of $t$ for which $M(t)$ is finite (and it *might* hold at one of the endpoint, but I am not sure).

Comment: @Thoth Note that existence of mgf at on all of $R$ requires $e^{-\omega(x)}$ tails while Subgaussianity requires tails of the order $e^{-\Omega(x^2)}$ and there are plenty of functions in $\omega(x)\setminus \Omega(x^2)$.